# .find is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi this is my problem im currently looping all the selected element using jquery selector and tried to use .find(Selector) of jquery but i think its not working or is it possible to find an element using this code

```
 for (var i = 0; i < $('.MainElement').find('.ItemGroup').length; i++) {
            var CurrentSelectedGroup = $('.MainElement').find('.ItemGroup')[i].find('span');
            }
```

I debugged this code and its returning a unavailable but when i tried to jquery select the element manually its working is it possible to do this??

i need to select the span inside the current element inside the loop

I have searched in google i didnt find any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though `eq()` as given below works, a better approach will be is to use [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) for iteration, as you are running your selector multiple times in your script

```
$('.MainElement').find('.ItemGroup').each(function(){
    var CurrentSelectedGroup = $(this).find('span');
})
```

or at the least cache the value of your selector and then reuse it in your loop

Answer (score 1):

use **eq()**

```
var CurrentSelectedGroup = $('.MainElement').find('.ItemGroup').eq(i).find('span');
```

NOTE: **$('.MainElement').find('.ItemGroup')[i]** will return javascript object not jquery

Comment: Code dumps are not useful answers. Say **what** you changed, and **why**.

Answer (score 1):

Try this as it's much cleaner:

```
$('.MainElement').find('.ItemGroup').each(function() {
    var CurrentSelectedGroup = $(this).find('span');
});
```